# Meaning of ref class and gcnew

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, managed-c++

I am not clear about the usage of keywords **gcnew** and **ref class**. usually in C++ when we use keyword **new** for creating an object that time only the memory for the class allocated in Heap. As per I read about VC++ **ref class** when we use this token to create class then the memory for the class allocated in Heap before the object creation. is it true? if suppose it is to be true then what is the usage of **gcnew**. is **gcnew** does anything with reference count?

What is difference in below Handler creation statements

```
1)<class Name>  ^<handler> = gcnew <class Name>;
2)<class Name>  <handler>;
```

I know the first one allocates the memory in heap for that class. what about Second one, Usually in C++ if I create handler like this then the memory for that class is allocated in the stack, As per I read in C++/CLI programming when I creating a class using the token **ref class** then the memory for the class allocated in heap. I want to know whether the Second handler creation statement also creates the memory in heap.

Comment: For clarity, you are using the C++/CLI extensions (i.e. Managed C++) for working with the .NET Runtime and it's garbage collected memory heap, correct?

Comment: yes, you are correct.

Comment: Just keywords to tell the compiler that you meant to declare a type whose memory is managed by the garbage collector (ref class) and to allocate from the GC heap (gcnew).  As opposed to a native type (class), whose memory you manage yourself (new, delete).  In a C++/CLI program you can do both.  Be sure to follow at least an extensive tutorial, guessing at it can be painful.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thank you for the answer, for more clarity please answer if the handler creations like this, let me say I have ref class A and I am creating handler like this, A ^obj; is it allocate the memory in Stack.

Comment: Simply said, C++/CLI added more support for tracking objects and when the garbage collector should clean up the objects.
That is what ^, and gcnew (Garbage Collector New) are